# iOS app using Swift crashing only giving (lldb) as output

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, lldb, xcode6

First off, sorry if I'm putting too much in here:  I've put everything I think could be of use into the post.

I am writing an app which tries to render a horizontal Collection View within a Table View cell.  When no Collection View cells are being shown, i.e I have returned 0 for number of cells in that function, everything works fine.

But when I try to show a cell, the code crashes with no error messages except `(lldb)` in the output, and `EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`, highlighted in green over `0x2d5372:  movl   %esi, %eax`.

Clicking for the app to continue then crashes again with the same symptoms for each cell that needs to be shown, i.e each time `...cellForItemAtIndexPath...` function is called.

My code for the cell is:

```
class homeWhatsOnCellectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var filmTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var filmPoster: UIImageView!
}
```

And for the collection view is:

```
class homeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var onThisWeekCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        onThisWeekCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Home Whats On Collection View Cell")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {
        var cell: homeWhatsOnCellectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Home Whats On Collection View Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as homeWhatsOnCellectionCell
        cell.filmTitle.text = "The Hunger Games: Catching Fire"
        cell.filmPoster.image = UIImage(named: "The Hunger Games.jpg")
        return cell
}

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int {
        return 1
}
```

And finally, clicking continue on the final unexplained crash, crashes again with an error message that I cannot figure out.  Bonus if you can explain this as well.  I can sort of understand the error code, what it means, but not what is causing it or how to fix it:

Error Code:

```
2014-07-24 13:19:27.237 Films 2[22583:364445] -[UICollectionViewCell filmTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a185600
2014-07-24 13:19:27.240 Films 2[22583:364445] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell filmTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a185600'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0058d646 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f058bf objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00594fb5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x004de617 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x004de1de _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Films 2                             0x00100954 _TFC21Films_223homeTableViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTGSQCSo16UICollectionView_22cellForItemAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__GSQCSo20UICollectionViewCell_ + 980
    6   Films 2                             0x00100e55 _TToFC21Films_223homeTableViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTGSQCSo16UICollectionView_22cellForItemAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__GSQCSo20UICollectionViewCell_ + 101
    7   UIKit                               0x0149747d -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 258
    8   UIKit                               0x01499312 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4928
    9   UIKit                               0x0149d7bf -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 263
    10  UIKit                               0x00e1fcf9 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 600
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f18771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    12  QuartzCore                          0x04655f0f -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
    13  QuartzCore                          0x04649d95 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 397
    14  QuartzCore                          0x04649bf0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    15  QuartzCore                          0x045a925e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
    16  QuartzCore                          0x045aa624 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0466f1b9 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
    18  UIKit                               0x00d92e36 -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 39
    19  UIKit                               0x00d93d2b -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3027
    20  UIKit                               0x00dac3bb __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    21  UIKit                               0x00d923c1 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x035c405e __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x035c3ca4 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x035d56e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x004b1450 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x004a66f3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x004a654b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x004a57eb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x004a561b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    30  UIKit                               0x00d91dd0 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    31  UIKit                               0x00d953d6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    32  Films 2                             0x00102841 top_level_code + 97
    33  Films 2                             0x0010287b main + 43
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x02458ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

When this crashes, it highlights the `cell.filmTitle.text = "The Hunger Games: Catching Fire"`
 line, and I've checked that all outlets are connected as they should be, and as far as I can see everything should be connected fine.

Comment: Might not be the actual issue but not calling `super.viewDidLoad()` in your `viewDidLoad` might cause some odd things

Comment: Oh right, thanks.  That didn't solve the issue, but thanks for the tip

Comment: Have you tried to delete the outlet connections and reconnect again? I had similar crashes when upgrading XCode from beta 3 to beta 4 and reconnecting the outlets solved that.

Comment: @zisoft I deleted all outlet connections to the cell and the storyboard, as well as reconnecting the delegate and datasource for the collection view, but unfortunately the issue is still there...  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're registering the wrong class for reuse. You're using this.

```
onThisWeekCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Home Whats On Collection View Cell")
```

When you should be using your subclass.

```
onThisWeekCollectionView.registerClass(homeWhatsOnCellectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Home Whats On Collection View Cell")
```

Which leeds me to the meaningful part of your error.

> -[UICollectionViewCell filmTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Means that somewhere along the line, you tried to call the filmTitle method on an instance of UICollectionViewCell, and that instance didn't respond to the selector, which caused the crash. In this case, even though you were down casting in cellForRowAtIndexPath, the class that was being used for reuse was still your cells superclass, which wouldn't respond to any methods/properties added by your subclass.

Note: By standard naming conventions, your classes should start with capital letters.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, that's it.  Unfortunately now I'm getting a fatal error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the cell.filmTitle.text line.  Normally this would suggest to me that I hadn't connected the filmTitle outlet properly, but in this case I have yet still receive this error.

Comment: And thanks for pointing the conventions out - I couldn't find Swift conventions anywhere so I just stuck to my Pythonic ones.  I'll change those

Comment: @Hyperion My first though would be an unlinked outlet as well. I would start by unlinking and then relinking the outlets, just to make sure nothing went wrong. And no problem, there still hasn't been a formal styling guide released, so this isn't set in stone, but some of the naming conventions in Swift are being borrowed from Objective C.

Comment: Hmm, I've deleted and relinked all outlets to do with the cell, as well as deleting and re-writing the code to do with those outlets, and yet I'm still getting the same error.  Any thoughts?  Or is this the sort of thing I should be asking another question for?

Comment: @Hyperion Nothing else is really jumping out at me. I think this would probably be suitable as a new question though (provided you can't find a duplicate anywhere). Sorry I couldn't be more help.